# c++/boost program_options one option disable other

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have code like this:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;
po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
    ("help", "produce help message")
    ("mode1", "")
    ("mode2", "");
po::variables_map var_map;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), var_map);
po::notify(var_map);
```

and my program can work only either in mode1 or mode2.
and I don't want syntax like this `--mode 0/1`, because of 
semantically this is completely different things.

So it will be possible to tell boost program_options
module to implement such semantic

no option -> error

mode1 -> ok

mode2 -> ok

mode1 mode2 -> error

?

Note: yes, I can use `var_map.count` and check this my self
after `po::notify`, but I see classes like these http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/value_semantic.html
in documentation, and I wonder can I use something from program_options to check such semantic.

Comment: In [this example](http://www.boost.org/libs/program_options/example/real.cpp) they seem to use the inspection of `var_map` approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Note: yes, I can use var_map.count and check this my self after po::notify, but I see classes like these value_semantic in documentation, and I wonder can I use something from program_options to check such semantic.

Mmm. Only so much you can do;

### Custom notifiers

You can use value-semantics to do this *during* notify:

```
po::options_description od;
od.add_options()
    ("mode1", po::bool_switch(&mode1)->notifier([&](bool b) { if (b && mode2) throw po::error{"Only one mode may be specified"}; }))
    ("mode2", po::bool_switch(&mode2)->notifier([&](bool b) { if (b && mode1) throw po::error{"Only one mode may be specified"}; }))
    ;
```

This still requires you to validate that either mode is specified separately:

```
if (!(mode1 || mode2))
    throw po::error("Mode must be specified");
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/333d8b68d4ceb8d4)</kbd>**

```
+ ./a.out
Mode must be specified
+ ./a.out --mode1
mode1: true mode2: false
+ ./a.out --mode2
mode1: false mode2: true
+ ./a.out --mode1 --mode2
Only one mode may be specified
+ ./a.out --mode2 --mode1
Only one mode may be specified
```

### Manual validation

You could do without the notifiers above and simple write the constraint as a NXOR:

```
if (mode1 == mode2)
    throw po::error("Exactly 1 of --mode1 and --mode2 must be specified");
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af67cca7f99930f8)</kbd>**

### Hightech

You could of course have all options result in a custom type and make the notifiers aware of the logic.

<strike>I'll try to demo this.</strike> Update: This is a dead end since all value semantics imply an (optional) argument. This at the very least makes things ugly.

I was thinking along there lines: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7bd9072f3fa024e

```
    enum class Mode {
        mode1 = 1,
        mode2 = 2 
    };

    using mode_select = boost::optional<Mode>;

    mode_select mode;

    po::options_description od;
    od.add_options()
        ("mode1", po::value<mode_select>(&mode)->implicit_value(Mode::mode1, ""))
        ("mode2", po::value<mode_select>(&mode)->implicit_value(Mode::mode2, ""))
        ;
```

As you can see, things don't quite work out the way I'd like them to

Comment: Thanks a lot for such detailed answer.