# boost program_options: Read in 3d Vector as Command Line Parameter

Tags: c++, boost

I have

```
boost::program_options::options_description desc("Required options");                                             
desc.add_options()(                                                                                                                
  detail::enu_orig_lat_opt,                                               
  boost::program_options::value<float>(),                                 
  "Origin of enu latitudinal coordinates."                                                                        
)(                                                                                                                
  detail::enu_orig_lng_opt,                                               
  boost::program_options::value<float>(),                                 
  "Origin of enu longitudinal coordinates."                                                                       
)(                                                                                                                
  detail::enu_orig_alt_opt,                                               
  boost::program_options::value<float>(),                                 
  "Origin of enu altitude coordinates."                                                                       
);
```

I could use a single option that has a `multitoken` value and have it be of type `std::vector<float>` or I could use a struct with three fields and use a value of that type. So far to date I have struggled with both these options and have not been able to get them to work. The problem with the option above (see code) is that if the user only specifies one of the values I have to add code to validate the existence of the others.

So I really have two questions here. One, does anyone have sample code of reading a 3d vector including negative floats as command line options? Or two if not what is the ideal way to make sure that the three related options are all specified if any one or more are set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the subject of validating groups of options see this related answer: [c++/boost program_options one option disable other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701144/c-boost-program-options-one-option-disable-other)

The simplest way would be to make your vector type istreamable:

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ydI3cbXyjRr1WzB4)**

```
#include <iosfwd>
#include <istream>

template <typename T> struct LLA { 
    T lat, lon, alt;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, LLA& lla) {
        char ch;
        if (is >> lla.lat >> ch && ch == ';'
         && is >> lla.lon >> ch && ch == ';'
         && is >> lla.alt)
            return is;
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
        return is;
    }
};

using Origin = LLA<float>;

#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Origin origin;

    po::options_description desc;
    desc.add_options()
        ("origin,o", po::value(&origin), "origin of enu (lat;lon;alt)")
        ;

    auto parsed = po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc, po::command_line_style::default_style);
    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(parsed, vm);
    po::notify(vm);

    std::cout << "Origin: lat:" << origin.lat << " lon:" << origin.lon << " alt:" << origin.alt << "\n";
}
```

Will print e.g.

```
Origin: lat:3 lon:-5 alt:7
```

When invoked with e.g.

```
./test --origin='3;-5;7'
./test --origin '3;-5;7'
./test -0 '3;-5;7'
```