# Regular expression to validate syntax of fields in any order, with acceptable values

Tags: c++, regex, boost, tokenize

Consider the following situation:
We want to use a regular expression to validate the syntax of a command with X number of fields -   one  mandatory, two optional.   The three fields can be shown in any order, with any number of spaces separating them, and have limited dictionaries of acceptable values

```
Mandatory Field:  "-foo"
Optional Field 1:  Can be either of "-handle" "-bar" or "-mustache"
Optional Field 2:  Can be either of "-meow" "-mix" or "-want"
```

Examples of valid inputs:

```
-foo
-foo           -bar
-foo-want
-foo -meow-bar
-foo-mix-mustache
-handle      -foo-meow
-mustache-foo
-mustache -mix -foo
-want-foo
-want-meow-foo
-want-foo-meow
```

Examples of invalid inputs:

```
woof
-handle-meow
-ha-foondle
meow
-foobar
stackoverflow
- handle -foo -mix
-handle -mix
-foo -handle -bar
-foo -handle -mix -sodium
```

I guess you can say, there are three capture groups, with the first being mandatory and the last two being optional:

```
(\-foo){1}
(\-handle|\-bar|\-mustache)?
(\-meow|\-mix|\-want)?
```

But I'm not sure on how to write it so that these can be in any order, possibly separated by any amount of spaces, and with nothing else.

What I have so far is three forward-looking capture groups: (% signs indicating stuff to be completed)

```
^(?=.*?(foo))(?=.*?(\-handle|\-bar|\-mustache))(?=.*?(\-meow|\-mix|\-want))%Verify that group 1 is present once, optional groups 2 and 3 zero or one times, in any order,  with any spaces%$
```

Adding a new capture group is simple enough, or expanding the acceptable inputs for an existing group, but I'm definitely stumped on the backreferencing, and not quite sure how on how expanding  the checks to accomodate a 4th group would affect the backreferencing.

Or would it make more sense to just  use something like boost::split or boost::tokenize on the "-" character, then  iterate through them, counting the tokens that fit into group 1, 2, 3, and "none of the above," and verifying the counts?

It seems like  it should be a simple extension or application of a boost library.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you've decided to go with regular expressions? While there's a solution in here it seems overly complicated.

Comment: I know I'm overengineering this.   Maybe  regular expressions aren't the answer, but  I feel like there must be a boost libary that could implement this functionality elegantly.   A Context Free grammar or something.    We basically have 3 fields,  each with a defined set of acceptable values.   One  field is mandatory, the other two are optional, and all three can occur in any order.

Comment: Jared B's answer is probably as close as you'll get to this elegant functionality with Boost. With it, I believe you can still operate on string _parameter values_ with regular expressions, if that's what you're going for. Regex is designed to solve a specific set of string problems and, while you can do this, it's definitely on the edge of its purpose :)

Comment: Are two items from the *same* field allowed? Why is `-want-meow-foo` valid but `-foo -handle -bar` not?

Comment: @Galik I've assumed it shouldn't be allowed in my answer.

Comment: @Galik,   nope, I screwed up when writing examples.  :)   Nice catch

Comment: Honestly I'd just split on whitespace and examine what's in each column. There's no need for anything more complicated than that, is there? (Like the two _monstrous_ solutions given below...)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I would be interested to see how simple a raw string processing solution could be ;-)

Comment: @Galik: Maybe tomorrow... [I'll find my waaaaaaay hooome  ]

Answer (score 2):

You mention boost. Have you looked at program_options? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html

Comment: That looks similar to what I want, but  I'm looking specifically to operate on string data, not  necessarily program options.

Comment: It's going to be VeryHard™ to achieve what you want here with Boost PO, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701144/c-boost-program-options-one-option-disable-other/33702844#33702844

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, a context-free grammar would be fine. Let's parse your command into a structure like:

```
struct Command {
    std::string one, two, three;
};
```

Now, when we adapt that as a fusion sequence, we can write a Spirit Qi grammar for it and enjoy *automagic* attribute propagation:

```
CommandParser() : CommandParser::base_type(start) {
    using namespace qi;

    command = field(Ref(&f1)) ^ field(Ref(&f2)) ^ field(Ref(&f3));
    field   = '-' >> raw[lazy(*_r1)];

    f1 += "foo";
    f2 += "handle", "bar", "mustache";
    f3 += "meow", "mix", "want";

    start   = skip(blank) [ command >> eoi ] >> eps(is_valid(_val));
}
```

Here, everything is straight-forward: the [permutation parser (`operator^`)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/permutation.html) allows all three fields in any order.

f1, f2, f3 are the accepted symbols (`Options`, below) for the respective fields.

The start rule, finally, adds the skipping of blanks, and checks at the end (have we reached `eoi`? is the mandatory field present?).

### Live Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a6d6537b3262a1f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
struct Command {
    std::string one, two, three;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Command, one, two, three)

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It> 
struct CommandParser : qi::grammar<It, Command()> {
    CommandParser() : CommandParser::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        command = field(Ref(&f1)) ^ field(Ref(&f2)) ^ field(Ref(&f3));
        field   = '-' >> raw[lazy(*_r1)];

        f1 += "foo";
        f2 += "handle", "bar", "mustache";
        f3 += "meow", "mix", "want";

        start   = skip(blank) [ command >> eoi ] >> eps(is_valid(_val));
    }
  private:
    // mandatory field check
    struct is_valid_f {
        bool operator()(Command const& cmd) const { return cmd.one.size(); }
    };
    boost::phoenix::function<is_valid_f> is_valid;

    // rules and skippers
    using Options = qi::symbols<char>;
    using Ref     = Options const*;
    using Skipper = qi::blank_type;

    qi::rule<It, Command()> start;
    qi::rule<It, Command(), Skipper> command;
    qi::rule<It, std::string(Ref)> field;

    // option values
    Options f1, f2, f3;
};

boost::optional<Command> parse(std::string const& input) {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;

    Command cmd;
    bool ok = parse(input.begin(), input.end(), CommandParser<It>{}, cmd);

    return boost::make_optional(ok, cmd);
}

#include <iomanip>
void run_test(std::string const& input, bool expect_valid) {
    auto result = parse(input);

    std::cout << (expect_valid == !!result?"PASS":"FAIL") << "\t" << std::quoted(input) << "\n";
    if (result) {
        using boost::fusion::operator<<;
        std::cout << " --> Parsed: " << *result << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    char const* valid[] = { 
        "-foo",
        "-foo           -bar",
        "-foo-want",
        "-foo -meow-bar",
        "-foo-mix-mustache",
        "-handle      -foo-meow",
        "-mustache-foo",
        "-mustache -mix -foo",
        "-want-foo",
        "-want-meow-foo",
        "-want-foo-meow",
    };
    char const* invalid[] = {
        "woof",
        "-handle-meow",
        "-ha-foondle",
        "meow",
        "-foobar",
        "stackoverflow",
        "- handle -foo -mix",
        "-handle -mix",
        "-foo -handle -bar",
        "-foo -handle -mix -sodium",
    };

    std::cout << " === Positive test cases:\n";
    for (auto test : valid)   run_test(test, true);
    std::cout << " === Negative test cases:\n";
    for (auto test : invalid) run_test(test, false);
}
```

Prints

```
 === Positive test cases:
PASS    "-foo"
 --> Parsed: (foo  )
PASS    "-foo           -bar"
 --> Parsed: (foo bar )
PASS    "-foo-want"
 --> Parsed: (foo  want)
PASS    "-foo -meow-bar"
 --> Parsed: (foo bar meow)
PASS    "-foo-mix-mustache"
 --> Parsed: (foo mustache mix)
PASS    "-handle      -foo-meow"
 --> Parsed: (foo handle meow)
PASS    "-mustache-foo"
 --> Parsed: (foo mustache )
PASS    "-mustache -mix -foo"
 --> Parsed: (foo mustache mix)
PASS    "-want-foo"
 --> Parsed: (foo  want)
FAIL    "-want-meow-foo"
FAIL    "-want-foo-meow"
 === Negative test cases:
PASS    "woof"
PASS    "-handle-meow"
PASS    "-ha-foondle"
PASS    "meow"
PASS    "-foobar"
PASS    "stackoverflow"
PASS    "- handle -foo -mix"
PASS    "-handle -mix"
PASS    "-foo -handle -bar"
PASS    "-foo -handle -mix -sodium"
```

Comment: Just to show how nice _automagic_ attribute propagation is, here's a [slightly modified (2 lines...)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1287f8181e8944c9) version that makes the data members `optional<string>`. It does make for slightly prettier output out of the box.

Comment: Interesting,  I'll definitely have to read up on the syntax of the libraries used, to wrap my head around how it's working and how to adapt it for the purposes I want.       Especially since it's been about 8-10 years since I dipped into CFGs.  Seems incredibly powerful.

The existence of a permutation parser definitely helps.    I'm a bit surprised at the manual verification on the required field.   Will do some reading on if there's some default validation that can be triggered from  the use of boost::optional as well.

Thank you for the help. This'll a powerful tool  if I figure it out.

Comment: \*ahem\* _whether_

Comment: The validation for the boost-optional case is shown in my first comment. Really, Spirit's parser model is PEG and it's more capable than just CFG

Comment: One question:   Why do we need to use a fusion structure, when all the container items are strings?

Comment: What "container"? Also, the fusion adaptor adapts the `struct`, not the `string` (indeed, just a `vector<string>`, `optional<string>`, `std::list<std::vector<boost::optional<boost::variant<int, std::set<std::string> >>>>` would not require custom adaptation :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Here's [a standard-library-only version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd3e3c53262ba43e), by the way, if the existing answers weren't "monstrous" enough :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a **brute force** solution which should work for fairly simple cases.

The idea is to build up a *regular expression* out of all the permutations of the order in which these capture group can appear.

In the test data there are only `6` permutations. Obviously this method could get unwieldily pretty easily.

```
// Build all the permutations into a regex.
std::regex const e{[]{

    std::string e;

    char const* grps[] =
    {
        "\\s*(-foo)",
        "\\s*(-handle|-bar|-mustache)?",
        "\\s*(-meow|-mix|-want)?",
    };

    // initial permutation
    std::sort(std::begin(grps), std::end(grps));

    auto sep = "";

    do
    {
        e = e + sep + "(?:";
        for(auto const* g: grps)
            e += g;
        e += ")";
        sep = "|"; // separate each permutation with |
    }
    while(std::next_permutation(std::begin(grps), std::end(grps)));

    return e;

}(), std::regex_constants::optimize};

// Do some tests

std::vector<std::string> const tests =
{
    "-foo",
    "-foo           -bar",
    "-foo-want",
    "-foo -meow-bar",
    "-foo-mix-mustache",
    "-handle      -foo-meow",
    "-mustache-foo",
    "-mustache -mix -foo",
    "-want-foo",
    "-want-meow-foo",
    "-want-foo-meow",
    "woof",
    "-handle-meow",
    "-ha-foondle",
    "meow",
    "-foobar",
    "stackoverflow",
    "- handle -foo -mix",
    "-handle -mix",
    "-foo -handle -bar",
    "-foo -handle -mix -sodium",
};

std::smatch m;
for(auto const& test: tests)
{
    if(!std::regex_match(test, m, e))
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid: " << test << '\n';
        continue;
    }
    std::cout << "Valid: " << test << '\n';
}
```